# Effect using withLatestFrom called it even ofType(action) was not fired

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am using Angular 5, ngrx/store. I have an effect:

```
@Effect()
  updateAfterChanges$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.ChangesInItems),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.select(fromReducers.getItemsList)
    ),
    switchMap(([action, itemsList]: [ActionType, Items[]]) => {
       return [new UpdateItems()]
    })
)
```

`getItemsList` looks like this:

```
export const getItemsList= createSelector(
  fromAnotherReducer.getAllItems,
  getCurerntItemdId,
  (allItems, itemId) => collectItems(allItems, allItems[itemId].subItems)
);
```

This selector called on absolutely another page - `page1`. Where i don't have items at all. Items are loaded from the server when i open model window on `page2`.
So on the `page1` i am getting an error `Cannot read property 'subItems' of undefined`. Why this selector even called not after `ofType(ActionTypes.ChangesInItems)`? I must add a check in selector:

```
Object.keys(allItems).length !== 0 ?
    collectItems(allItems, allItems[itemId].subItems) : []
```

Why is this happening? I don't want to add checks in every selector that uses dynamically loaded  data. I expect that effect will be called only in response to `ofType(ActionTypes.ChangesInItems)`

Answer (score 1):

As you use it here, `withLatestFrom` will always be executed. You don't need logic to check for items, tweak your structure a bit:

```
@Effect()
updateAfterChanges$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionTypes.ChangesInItems),
  switchMap(action => {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(fromReducers.getItemsList),
      map(items => {
        return [new UpdateItems()]
      }),
    );
  }),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behaviour, it's how **withLatestFrom** works, so it will start listening to the given observable **immediately**, but it will only emit the value when source get emitted!

This [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/withlatestfrom-test?file=index.ts) will explain what’s happening:

So the console.log inside `test()` will shown immediately but the returned value from `test()` will only shown when the click event triggered